# how to assign value in form data in angular

Tags: javascript, postman, multipartform-data, angular14

I am trying to fetch data from parameter in fromdata  but it is not get append in the variable

```
onSubmitBasic(AirportDetails1) {
```

```
var formdata = new FormData();formdata.append('airport_city', AirportDetails1.airport_city);this.http.post(${environment.apiUrl}Airport_Mgt/Register_airport, formdata,options).subscribe((response) => {this.User = response;console.log("Airportdata", this.Airportdata);});}
```

```
output formdata{}expect formdata{'airport_city','delhi'}
```

```
output: Airportdata undefined
```

Comment: Please format correctly your code or provide a stackblitz with the issue reproduced

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to console this.User instead of this.Airportdata. Also follow camelCase for naming convention.

Comment: I try this also no response